# How do I style a container relative to device screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am building an app in react native and would like to style the container to be relative to the top of the device of the user. Right now I just have margin-top: 20 but that still looks bad on a lot of devices. I need something like margin-top: topofscreen + 20

```
container:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 5,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
},
```

Comment: What does 'be relative to the top of the device of the user' mean? if you want the margin-top to be dynamic depends on the type of the devices, like some devices have notch, you can use SafeAreaView or just import a third part library react-native-device-info, and determine it by using hasNotch()

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, dynamic depending on the type of device. Thanks for your comments